# CASE expression in combination conditional fields format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, case-when

Trying to write a CASE expression where I need to evaluate `Family_size` and `Income` in combinations to set the `Status` AS Below if any of the combinations is true.

```
CASE
    ((WHEN Family_size = 1 AND Income <=11800)
      OR(WHEN Family_size = 2 AND Income <=16020)
      OR(WHEN Family_size = 3 AND Income <=20160)
      OR(WHEN Family_size = 4 AND Income <=24300)
      OR(WHEN Family_size = 5 AND Income <=28400)
      OR(WHEN Family_size = 6 AND Income <=32580)
      OR(WHEN Family_size = 7 AND Income <=36730)
      OR(WHEN Family_size = 8 AND Income <=40890)
     THEN 'Below' ELSE 'Above' END) AS [Status]
```

This gives the error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'

Is there a neat trick or will I have to write `THEN 'Below'` individually? Like:

```
CASE
      WHEN Family_size = 1 AND Income <=11800 THEN 'Below'
      WHEN Family_size = 2 AND Income <=16020 THEN 'Below'
and so on...
```

Comment: `WHEN` **once** and then just `OR` your conditions

Comment: What you are suggesting is completely valid.

Comment: I didn't know whom to up vote amongst the duplicate answers so both I guess lol

Comment: @PM77-1 Do the braces make a difference to enforce conditional checking in pairs or is the part before `OR` checked separately from the part after it? Like Family_size < 7 AND Income <=1234 OR Family_size >=7 AND Income <=2345

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a correction based on the **[federal poverty guideline 2016](https://aspe.hhs.gov/computations-2016-poverty-guidelines)**.

Additional correction based on these **[poverty guidelines](https://aspe.hhs.gov/poverty-guidelines)** to include family sizes greater than 8.

```
select [Status] =
  case
  when (Family_size = 1 and Income <=11880) -- Corrected to 11880 for federal poverty guideline 2016
     or(Family_size = 2 and Income <=16020)
     or(Family_size = 3 and Income <=20160)
     or(Family_size = 4 and Income <=24300)
     or(Family_size = 5 and Income <=28440) -- Corrected to 28440  for federal poverty guideline 2016
     or(Family_size = 6 and Income <=32580)
     or(Family_size = 7 and Income <=36730)
     or(Family_size = 8 and Income <=40890)
  then 'Below' else 'Above' end as
```

could be rewritten as:

```
select [Status] = case
     when  Family_size < 7  and Income <= (11880 + ((family_size-1)*4140)) 
      then 'Below'
     when  Family_size >= 7 and Income <= (36730 + ((family_size-7)*4160)) 
      then 'Below'
      else 'Above' 
      end
```

To confirm that the equations are correct in the above case statement, you can check this rextester link which uses the same equations to generate the poverty table for 1-12: **http://rextester.com/AWRCK1808**

You may need to take into account the state, as Alaska and Hawaii have different numbers for poverty.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Is (11880 + (family_size -1)*4140) a federal standard formula for families below 7 members?

Comment: Yes. 7 gets 4150 for the 7th head. 8 and above get 4160 per head after the 7th.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN (Family_size = 1 AND Income <=11800)
      OR(Family_size = 2 AND Income <=16020)
      OR(Family_size = 3 AND Income <=20160)
      OR(Family_size = 4 AND Income <=24300)
      OR(Family_size = 5 AND Income <=28400)
      OR(Family_size = 6 AND Income <=32580)
      OR(Family_size = 7 AND Income <=36730)
      OR(Family_size = 8 AND Income <=40890)
     THEN 'Below' ELSE 'Above' END AS [Status]
```

Answer (score 2):

As commented above try:

```
 CASE WHEN (Family_size = 1 AND Income <=11800)
   OR (Family_size = 2 AND Income <=16020)
   OR (Family_size = 3 AND Income <=20160)
   OR (Family_size = 4 AND Income <=24300)
   OR (Family_size = 5 AND Income <=28400)
   OR (Family_size = 6 AND Income <=32580)
   OR (Family_size = 7 AND Income <=36730)
   OR (Family_size = 8 AND Income <=40890)
     THEN 'Below' ELSE 'Above' END AS [Status]
```